# AS3 removing MovieClips in an array

Tags: flash, arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, object

Anybody any ideas on how to remove children from stage using AS3 if I store the reference to the objects in an array and they exist in different locations i.e they are not all children of the same parent?

SomeArray.push(this);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for each(var mc:MovieClip in SomeArray){
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: this makes some assumptions, ideally you'd do it with a bit more fool-proofing, like checking if each mc does have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this :

- Iterate over each of the clips &
  their children.
- Match the reference name/ID (I hope
  its a unique one).
- Use removeChild to remove the display
  object(Sprite,MC,etc).
- keep popping off the last reference off the array as you keep getting matches.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I have 3 collision objects that I attach children to but I want to keep the number of children inside all 3 objects to a maximum as not to soak up too much cpu.